# Javascript implicit parameter names for lambdas

Tags: javascript, swift, ecmascript-next

Does Javascript/ES8 have shorthand argument names, like Swift?

eg. `arr.sort { $0.name > $1.name }`

Comment: There's no such thing as ES8. If you mean modern ES editions, they are covered by 'Javascript', and proposals are referred as ES.next. JSX tag looks irrelevant here, and I would suggest to add Swift tag since it's essential for understanding the main point.

Comment: Btw, [that's not a usable comparison function anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

There are no shorthand arguments in Javascript. The closest alternatives are `arguments` and ES6 rest parameter.

```
function fn(param1, param2) {
  const $ = arguments;

  // by name
  console.log(param1, param2);

  // by order
  console.log($[0], $[1]);
}
```

Rest parameter it is more consistent than `arguments`, the latter isn't supported in arrow functions:

```
const fn = (...$) => {
  // by name
  let [param1, param2] = $;
  console.log(param1, param2);

  // by order
  console.log($[0], $[1]);
}
```

Notice that `$` parameter name is used to draw an analogy to Swift. It is not recommended to use `$` name in practice because it may be confused with conventional jQuery `$` variable. The conventional meaningful name for rest parameter that includes all arguments is `args`.

Comment: I would change `...$` to something like `...args` makes it easier to read. Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: `let { param1, param2 } = $;` should be `let [ param1, param2 ] = $` because `rest` operator returns an `Array`. But the point is: `OP` was about shorthand arguments not something similar.

Comment: @Mr.Baudin Thanks. $ is used solely to draw an analogy with Swift. `args` is by far more conventional and convenient.

Comment: @estus I understand and you are right ofc. Just wanted to add the comment to give a more "javascripty" way of naming the parameter. "I would change" was not directed to your answer so much as to the general idea of the solution. - I should have written a better comment. Great answer and sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 1):

No, javascript doesn't support `shorthand argument name`.